# Wordpress read more content

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

is it possible by any plugin or code modifications to show different contents on frontpage and on "Read more" click. So, could I make a post which looks different on the frontpage and on the article page, so once someone clicks it shows a different post or content.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the_excerpt?

[wordpress codex - the_excerpt();](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_excerpt/)

You can also modify the excerpt read more text which defaults to [...] by adding a filter.

```
/**
 * Filter the excerpt "read more" string.
 *
 * @param string $more "Read more" excerpt string.
 * @return string (Maybe) modified "read more" excerpt string.
 */
function wpdocs_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return 'Custom read more text';
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'wpdocs_excerpt_more' );
```

The excerpt itself is set within the create/edit post in the admin.

You may need need to show the field in the admin which can be done in the screen options at the top of the create/edit post in the admin.

If you require more freedom than the_excerpt provides, I would suggest using custom meta.